# Xmlhttprequest returns Access is denied on IE only

Tags: javascript, xml, json, http, post

I'm using the code below and it's working fine on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE7 it says Access is denied. I've read a lot of stuff on this issue but still happens.

```
Test.GetContent = function (x, params, callback, optional) {
    var result = "";
    var url = "http://" + this.ip + "/test/getstuff.php?";
    var req = this.CreateXMLHTTPObject();
    if (!req)
        return "Browser Incompatibility";

    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState != 4) return;
        if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {

            return;
        }
        callback.call(Test, JSON.parse(req.responseText), optional);
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send(JSON.stringify(params));
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be cross-domain, would it?

Comment: If it is cross-origin, [IE7 doesn't support CORS](http://caniuse.com/cors).

Comment: Yes it's cross domain but it's also happening on IE8,9 and 10

Answer (score 0):

IE is different, I think you need to handle it different.  This defines the xmlhttp variable no matter which browser runs it.

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Comment: It's not included in the post, but I'd guess that this is likely what `this.CreateXMLHTTPObject()` is already trying to do.

Comment: yes the method this.CreateXMLHTTPObject() return the right variable, i'm trying for XMLHttpRequest, Microsoft.XMLHTTP and so on. The thing about this is that it's happening with ie8, 9 and 10 too